# Configuration instead of Attributes with SQLite.Net-PCL

Tags: xamarin, sqlite-net

Is there a way to use [SQLite.Net-PCL](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL)
without adding attribute to the class properties, so it can stay a clean POCO, and use a configuration/mapping classes instead?